# How do I use doxygen to generate the internal documentation for Unity?

Tags: unity, doxygen

[The Hacking file for Unity](https://gitorious.org/ubuntu-omap/unity/source/7ef3c26371b40345c7dca46adb32d998986a9c55:HACKING) says:

> Internal Documentation can be built for Unity by having doxygen installed and running `make doxygen`.

I'm not familiar with doxygen and could use some help in the specific command(s) to use.

I downloaded the Unity source using: `bzr branch lp:unity` and ran `doxygen Doxyfile.in`.

It generated `api-doc/html` with a number of files, but `index.html` loads an empty framework.

I read the man file and the [online manual/faq](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/index.html) but am still not sure what I need to do.

Answer (score 3):

I got this working. I had assumed that the `Doxyfile.in` file was setup for any system and that all I had to do was run `doxygen Doxyfile.in`.

In fact, I discovered that doxygen expects to be run as cmake target, but I wasn't looking to do the entire build just yet.

To run doxygen as a stand alone process, I needed to edit the `Input` section of the `Doxyfile.in` with the actual path to the source file directory, commenting out the existing path variables that are there for use with the make file.

After that, `doxygen Doxyfile.in` worked fine.